# Static files setting in Nginx？

Tags: nginx

I want 'www.mydomain.com/images/20151111/test.jpg' could be visit
And I am sure the 'test.jpg' is realy exist.
but It shows 404 not found.
Here is my nginx setting.

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    index index.html
    root /home/googleimage;


    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/pic.sock;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
            {
                root /home/wechat;
                    expires      30d;
            }

    location /images/ {
        alias /home/images/;
    }

}
```

The 'test.jpg' in this floder 
/home/images/20151111/test.jpg

what was wrong?

Comment: it matches `location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$`

Comment: `~` is for a case-sensitive regex, are you sure your filename is `test.jpg` and not `Test.JPG` (etc)?  Try using `~*` for case-insensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI `/images/20151111/test.jpg` matches your `regex location` first, as this takes precedence. To make your `prefix location` take precedence write is as:

```
location ^~ /images/ {
  alias /home/images/;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for `location` syntax and usage.